# How can I make my image rotate about a fixed point when using bitmap?

Tags: android

I'm trying to rotate an image at a fixed point, but the image is rotating at its top left position. I've tried rotateAnimation and it works fine, but the problem is when I rotate my image again it starts rotating from the original position.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arw2);
int w = bmp.getWidth();
int h = bmp.getHeight();
float px = 160,py = 215;
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
mtx.setRotate(rAngle, px, py);
Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBMP);
myImageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check where is your pivot(160, 215) relative to the image size?

Comment: yes, I've checked it...I changed my pivot points relative to image size but it is rotating in same manner around top left pivot point.Can you give me a solution of that doing it in rotate animation..It rotate my image as I want but when i want to rotate it again it start rotating from initial position..will you please guide me I want that when i rotate my image again it start from last stopping point where first animation ends.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to rotate an image once, and then a second time, from where it left off.

You *could* do this by rotating the image by 30 degrees once, and then rotating that image again by 30 degrees (60 degrees in total), but this would result in a loss in quality and the centre point would be incorrect.

A better solution would be simply to change the value of `rAngle` that you use each time, and always create the rotated image based on the original un-rotated source image. So rather than rotating by (e.g.) 30 degrees each time, you rotate by 30 degrees or 60 degrees or 90 degrees etc.

If you wanted an image to rotate 30 degrees each time a button was clicked, you'd store the number of clicks in a variable such as `buttonClicks`, and then set `rAngle = buttonClicks * 30` and perform the rotation.